# How to display superscript % character as string in UIlabel?

Tags: ios, unicode, uilabel

How to display superscript % character as string in UIlabel? I know % does not exist in unicode as a superscript but is there is any way we can display % as a superscript instead of using html tags??

Comment: This article might do what you want: http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/drawing-nsattributedstrings-with.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. Now i am able to display the % as superscript for label using that article

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found this post on Stackoverflow on superscript styling text using attributed string:

[NSAttributedString superscript styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415963/nsattributedstring-superscript-styling)

So using that, I hacked up this demo:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20];

    UILabel *textBlock1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0)];
    textBlock1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    textBlock1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    textBlock1.font = font;

    textBlock1.text = @"57%";





    UILabel *textBlock2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0)];
    textBlock2.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    textBlock2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"57%"
                                                                                         attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font}];
    [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10]
                                      , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @10} range:NSMakeRange(2, 1)];

    textBlock2.attributedText = attributedString;



    [self.view addSubview:textBlock1];
    [self.view addSubview:textBlock2];
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing the source. I have achieved the same using the tutorial http://sketchytech.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/drawing-nsattributedstrings-with.html suggested by trojanfoe.

Comment: @Zhang Can you make a small translation into Swift? Since some commands are changed and I try hard to archive the same. Thanks

Comment: @Nicholas it's pretty much the exact same thing in Swift, not sure what you mean by some commands are changed, but it's a pretty copy paste/convert translation....

Comment: I also want to point out that NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName is not good for all scenarios, because you have to set a magic number, if you ever set a min/max font size this will not scale right.

Comment: @TheCodingArt Thanks, I'll give it a second try. My main issues are related to this kind of use in other contexts such as uiswitches and uibuttons not only uilabels

Answer (score 1):

For a **simple to use Swift solution**, you might want to checkout **[HandyUIKit](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit)**. After importing it into your project (e.g. via Carthage – see instructions in README) you can do something like this:

```
import HandyUIKit

"57^{%}".superscripted(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium))
```

This line will return an `NSAttributedString` which will look exactly like **what you're looking for**. Just **assign it** to a `UILabel`s **`attributedText`** property and **that's it!**

---

If you're looking for **subscripting** a text, simply use `subscripted(font:)` instead. It will recognize structures like `CO_{2}`. There's also `superAndSubscripted(font:)` if you want to combine **both**.

See the [docs](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit#superscriptedfont--subscriptedfont--superandsubscriptedfont) for more information and additional examples.