# how to implement this style in one label

Tags: ios, uilabel

[image]

I want to use only one UILabel to do this and the two areas 's bottom are not in same horizontal line.how can I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSAttributedString and adjust the baseline of that character.

[How to display superscript % character as string in UIlabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300066/how-to-display-superscript-character-as-string-in-uilabel)