# is it possible to display a date with say 22nd with nd displayed small top right

Tags: html, ios, iphone, xcode4

I need to be able to display dates in a table, with the date displayed as say 22nd Sept 2014, where the nd is shown as small text to the top right of the 22 as in most date displayed formats.
Using the  tag works in Html but not in IOS, does this format work in iOS?

Comment: Use attributed string..

Comment: There seems to be a solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415963/nsattributedstring-superscript-styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an *attributed string* for example from a `dateString` of type `NSString` having format `@"22nd Sept 2014"` (or whatever format, but "st", "nd" and "th" at 3rd and 4th index of string):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:dateString 
                                  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:yourLabel.font}];

[attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:yourLabel.font.fontName size:8]
                                  , NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:@8} range:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];

yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think you are saying to set the (nd or th) separately by specifying them as 3rd and 4th index of string. How would I then get them to display as they do in Html using <sup>?

Comment: No you don't need to separate them out.. You just have to create an attributedString as explained above and assign that value to you label or textview.. just don't assign text value to that object

Comment: Thank you Salman, I've tried with both the r Registered icon and with a small version of th/rd but it still displays as normal text. Have you a working version I could try?