# How to change the allignment of a character in Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

This is what I want to achieve.

[image]

I used an `attributedString`, took the range of character **$** and applied attributes to it like below way:

```
let str = "$4"
let r1 = str.range(of: "$")!
let n1 = NSRange(r1, in: str)
let atrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
atrStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)], range: n1)
atrStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.lightGray], range: n1)
lbl.attributedText = atrStr
```

But the result is

[image]

How do I change the allignment of that specific character from bottom to top?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415963/nsattributedstring-superscript-styling/21603232

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I missed this. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `baselineOffset` of `NSMutableAttributedString`

**calculate the diference between your two fonts sizes**

```
let offset = baseFont.capHeight - smallFont.capHeight
```

**Add the new attribute called baselineOffset**

```
atrStr.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset:offset], range: n1)
```

Comment: Hey @Reinier Melian, I am applying baselineOffset on CATextLayer but it's not working can you help?

Comment: @Nick i will review and update my answer

Comment: @Nick I have an example working you can post this as new question?